# Puppeteer error when opening more browsers

Tags: puppeteer

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRVgK.jpg)

I start the it with max-old-space-size `node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js`.

When I try to open more browsers I get this error, how could I fix it?

Comment: I sometimes get also `Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /home/container/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-938248/chrome-linux/chrome EAGAIN` error when I try to open more browsers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.